# How to convert an image from np.uint16 to np.uint8?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am creating an image so:

```
image = np.empty(shape=(height, width, 1), dtype = np.uint16)
```

After that I convert the image to BGR model:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

I'd like to convert the image now in a `dtype = np.uint8` in order to use that image with `cv2.threshold()` function. I meant, I would like to convert the image to `CV_8UC1`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `cv2.convertScaleAbs` for this problem. See the [Documentation.](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=convertscale#convertscaleabs)

Check out the command terminal demo below :

```
>>> img = np.empty((100,100,1),dtype = np.uint16)
>>> image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

>>> cvuint8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)

>>> cvuint8.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you to use this :

```
outputImg8U = cv2.convertScaleAbs(inputImg16U, alpha=(255.0/65535.0))
```

this will output a uint8 image & assign value between 0-255 with respect to there previous value between 0-65535

```
exemple :
pixel with value == 65535 will output with value 255 
pixel with value == 1300 will output with value 5 etc...
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you want to rescale uint16 range `0..65535` into uint8 range `0..255`. In other words, visually image will look the same, just lower color depth.

```
np_uint16 = np.arange(2 ** 16, dtype=np.uint16).reshape(256, 256)
np_uint8 = (np_int16 // 256).astype(np.uint8)
```

produces mapping:

```
[0..255] => 0 (256 values)
[256..511] => 1 (256 values)
... 
[65280..65535] => 255 (256 values)
```

#### Why two other answers are incorrect:

**Accepted one**

```
img = np.empty((100,100,1), dtype = np.uint16)
image = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cvuint8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)
```

^ will create an uninitialized uint16 array and then cast it to uint8 taking abs() and clipping values >255 to 255. Resulting mapping:

```
[0..254] => [0..254]
[255..65535] => 255
```

**Next one:**

```
outputImg8U = cv2.convertScaleAbs(inputImg16U, alpha=(255.0/65535.0))
```

^ produces slightly wrong mapping:

```
[0..128] => 0 (129 values)
[129..385] => 1 (257 values)
...
[65407..65535] => 255 (129 values)
```

so `2,..,254` bins get one extra value at `0` and `255`'s expense.
It's a bit tricky to get precise mapping with `convertScaleAbs`, since it uses **round half down**:

```
np_int16 = np.arange(2 ** 16, dtype=np.uint16).reshape(256, 256)
np_uint8 = cv2.convertScaleAbs(np_int16, alpha = 1./256., beta=-.49999)
```

ps: if you care about performance, OpenCV one is ~50% faster than Numpy on my Mac.

Comment: Great insight +1. How about using `cv2.normalize`?

Comment: @JeruLuke thanks! `normalize` will stretch your intensities, hence alter the image visually. If it's the goal - yep (i.e. you have a model that was trained on min-max normalized dataset).

Comment: the `np.empty` is a placeholder and warrants no comment at all. the truncation/wraparound does though.