# cv2.imshow() function displays correct image but while saving it using cv2.imwrite() funtion, its saves all black pixel image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-resizing

I am trying to resize the input image to 736 x 736 as output size preserving the aspect ratio of the original image and add zero paddings while doing so.
The function `image_resize_add_padding()` works fine and is doing what I am trying to do. The resized image looks good while displaying using `cv2.imshow()` function
but while saving using `cv2.imwrite()` function it seems to be a fully black image.

How do I save the correct image as it was displayed?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def image_resize_add_padding(image, target_size):
    ih, iw = target_size
    h,  w, _ = image.shape

    scale = min(iw/w, ih/h)
    nw, nh = int(scale * w), int(scale * h)
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image, (nw, nh))

    image_paded = np.full(shape=[ih, iw, 3], fill_value=128.0)
    dw, dh = (iw - nw) // 2, (ih-nh) // 2
    image_paded[dh:nh+dh, dw:nw+dw, :] = image_resized
    image_paded = image_paded / 255.

    return image_paded


input_size = 736
image_path = "test_image.jpg"
original_image = cv2.imread(image_path)
output_image = image_resize_add_padding(
    np.copy(original_image), [input_size, input_size])
cv2.imshow('image', output_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('test_output.jpg', output_image)
```

Comment: Did you try the steps on this post?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239381/pyplot-imsave-saves-image-correctly-but-cv2-imwrite-saved-the-same-image-as

Comment: @MightyDiffy thank you for the reference. The best answer in the post above says to multiply the output image by 255 to get the correct range. I did try it before or I could remove the part where I am dividing the image_paded output by 255. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The imshow function and imwrite using the JPG format handle floating-point image buffers differently.

The line where you divided the image by `255.` changed the image format to floating point. For the image data to be handled properly by the JPG writer, you can, for example, convert your buffer to uint8 (and make sure the values are in the range 0-255) before calling imwrite.

edit:

The code converts the image to floating point and also changes the range to 0-1. It is unclear why this is done, but if you want to keep the function as is, you can prepare the image for the `imwrite` call like this:

`output_image = (output_image * 255).astype('uint8')`

Comment: yea, just get rid of `image_paded = image_paded / 255.` and you're good to go.

Comment: @etienne-d as per you suggestion I converted the buffer by adding `output_image.astype('uint8') ` 
 as `cv2.imwrite('test_output.jpg', output_image)` but the result is same (full black image.) Am i missing something?

Comment: @Doyousketch2 I did tried it before but didn't work. Removing that `image_paded = image_paded / 255.`part will further additionally display wrong image (i.e. plane white image) and saves full black image. You can try ruinnng the code above by any sample image and see for your self.

Comment: Is your test image a regular rgb .JPG, or does it have transparency?  I know historically, CV2 had issues with jpg's.  They didn't add in the ability to read those for years.  Think people still avoid it 'cuz it introduces artifacts.  Ran the exact same code here with that line removed, and it was fine on a .PNG

Comment: The line with the `/255.` should not be there, but it's not the only problem, the image still gets converted to float. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @EtienneD. Perfect thanks for your updated version. It works like a charm.