# OpenCV findContours() complains if used with black-white image

Tags: python, opencv

I want to perform edge detection with the following code. However I get an error because of the image color depth. This error in my eyes, makes no sense, as I convert the image properly to a gray-scale image, and in a subsequent step to a black and white image, which is definitely working correctly. When I call `findContours` I get an error.

```
import cv2

def bw_scale(file_name, tresh_min, tresh_max):
    image = cv2.imread(file_name)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    #(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(image, tresh_min, tresh_max, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(image, tresh_min, tresh_max, 0)

    cv2.imwrite('bw_'+file_name, im_bw)
    return (thresh, im_bw)

def edge_detect(file_name, tresh_min, tresh_max):
    (thresh, im_bw) = bw_scale(file_name, tresh_min, tresh_max)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  edge_detect('test.jpg', 128, 255)
```

I get this error:

```
dgrat@linux-v3pk:~> python aoi.py
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images) in cvStartFindContours, file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp, line 196
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aoi.py", line 25, in <module>
    edge_detect('test.jpg', 128, 255)
  File "aoi.py", line 19, in edge_detect
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.error: /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:196: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images in function cvStartFindContours
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're misusing the return values of `cv2.threshold()`.

[cv2.threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold) returns 2 parameters:

- **retval**

  is used when thresholding using the OTSU method (returning the optimal threshold value) otherwise it returns the same threshold value you passed to the function, 128.0 in your case.
- **dst**

  is the thresholded result image

In your code `thresh` is a float not a Mat.

Change:

`contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

to

`contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`

## **EDIT**

Below find a refactored and simplified version of your original code using the following test image.

[image]

```
import cv2

def edge_detect(file_name, tresh_min, tresh_max):
    image = cv2.imread(file_name)
    im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    (thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_bw, tresh_min, tresh_max, 0)
    cv2.imwrite('bw_'+file_name, im_bw)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
    cv2.imwrite('cnt_'+file_name, image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  edge_detect('test.jpg', 128, 255)
```

This produces the following bw_test.jpg

[image]

With the following contours highlighted in cnt_test.jpg

[image]

Comment: Get still the same error. I wonder whether its a python problem or me.

Comment: I just run your code with the change mentioned in my post and it works with no error. Contours get detected properly.

Comment: No matter what I do, I always get this error. I will test it on a different pc :(

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE**

Considering that you already convert you image to gray scale, the problem should be with the channel range. `FindContours` support only `32s` and `8u`. You could use [`image.dtype`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html#accessing-image-properties) to make sure that you get something like `uint8`. If not `cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)` [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347141/2295964) solve your problem.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

As the error mentions `FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images`. So might want to use something like [`cv.CvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cv.CvtColor) to convert your image to a supported color space.

Comment: >> image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

Isn't this the right function?

Comment: Two concepts are important: number of channels and pixel representation. You may have grayscale picture but not in `8U` or `32S`.

Comment: Still same error with:     
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.CV_8UC1) \n
    image = cv2.convertScaleAbs(image)

Comment: @dgrat; do you need the `cvtColor` call before `convertScaleAbs` since by definition `convertScaleAbs` will "scale, take an abs value and convert to unsigned 8bit type"? Therefore the end result of `covnertScaleAbs` is `8uC#`. `convertScaleAbs` will do that _for each channel_ separately, which means that you don't change the number of channels. If you really have a b&w image you should have only 1 channel, if you have i.e. b&w image with transparency you will have additional "alpha" channel. If your error persists that means that you probably didn't convert it to b&w properly?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when trying with grayscale images, then i tried applying gaussian filter with average of 5X5 blocks with Canny edge detector to a cvtColor converted grayscaled image. Voila! contours on the pic.

Try this code

```
image = cv2.imread('testimage.jpeg')
im_bw = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_bw, (5,5), 0)
im_bw = cv2.Canny(blur, 10, 90)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(im_bw, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, `findContours` is returning only contours and hierarchy.

Before you pass on the image as a param to the function, it must be a `uint8` and must be grayscale. These worked when I used `RETR_CCOM` as the mode.