# Normalizing an image with OpenCV causes TypeError

Tags: python, opencv

I want to normalize a python array that looks like this

```
array([[ 11.40734340-0.29832373j,  11.43838953-0.2330848j ,
     11.51347743+0.05464141j, ...,  11.66593745-0.23486117j,
     11.48996430-0.18709683j,  11.47948371-0.28934914j],
   [ 11.53463463-0.20148586j,  11.58397234-0.10384628j,
     11.59314978+0.18854025j, ...,  11.44680114-0.38295714j,
     11.44062107-0.30858363j,  11.49362217-0.32352874j],
   [ 11.47423737-0.09162011j,  11.66564959+0.16699415j,
     11.57411499+0.27745924j, ...,  11.30369153-0.28317958j,
     11.60371236-0.33782883j,  11.51040077-0.28672312j],
   ..., 
   [ 11.15258074-0.19047382j,  11.21263244-0.26008457j,
     11.23572965-0.27349975j, ...,  11.26901318-0.25710196j,
     11.26925144-0.20500497j,  11.12739736-0.22942166j],
   [ 11.27209183-0.14971003j,  11.34077096-0.18473887j,
     11.28326221-0.40778278j, ...,  11.33564537-0.24436556j,
     11.42304835-0.26064881j,  11.37050821-0.21830381j],
   [ 11.39713540-0.33105119j,  11.47700146-0.22564029j,
     11.42977268-0.20060011j, ...,  11.37402085-0.22322532j,
     11.43500243-0.15516771j,  11.45758000-0.20336809j]])
```

to real values between 0 and 255 so that I can save it as a grayscale image. I'm having no luck with OpenCV:

```
image = complex_array.real
output = image
cv2.normalize(image, output, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

This yields an error: `TypeError: Layout of the output array dst is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)`. What does this mean in the context of `normalize()`?

Comment: `output` is the same thing as `image`, so its data type is not CV_8U, which is what you want to get. Considering that a reallocation will have to happen anyway due to the change in data type, why don't you just do `output = cv2.normalize(image, alpha......` instead of the last 2 lines of the snippet you've shown?

Comment: @DanMašek You can't do that, at least not in OpenCV 3.2.0 which I am using. The second argument is required. How would I go about creating `output` not as a copy of `image`, but as an array of type CV_8U then?

Comment: I found a suitable answer to my last question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337499/how-to-convert-an-image-from-np-uint16-to-np-uint8
So `cv2.convertScaleAbs` does the trick. @DanMašek If you want to post an answer I'll accept it  :)