# how to convert uint8 image to uint16 (PYTHON)

Tags: python, numpy

```
image1 = cv2.imread("82.png",0)
image2 = cv2.imread("83.png",0)

np.uint16(image1)
np.uint16(image2)
```

I want to convert image1 and image2 to uint16 type. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: so? you just did that.

Comment: Use `image1.astype(np.uint16)` (note the values are NOT renormalized) and consider reading: https://numpy.org/learn/

Comment: What happens when you run this code? What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an image from np.uint16 to np.uint8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337499/how-to-convert-an-image-from-np-uint16-to-np-uint8)

Comment: @MichaelS. it doesnt give error and also it doesnt change the type. the problem is I need to write it like this:  image1 = np.uint16(image1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve your goal by using np.astype()

EXAMPLE:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
        
image1 = cv2.imread("82.png",0)
image_uint16=image1.astype("uint16")
```